# jquery append to file object

Tags: jquery, arrays, file-upload

I am building an upload script and need to add something to the file object.

I get the list of files by doing the usual:

```
files = $("#Files")[0].files;
```

but I want to store an Id with each file that is uploaded, so I tried doing something like this:

```
$.each($("#Files")[0].files, function (i, file) {
    var t = file;
    t.push({ id: i });
    files.push(t);
});
```

but I get an error stating

> Object # has no method 'push'

which is understandable.

My question is that is there an easy way of either adding something to the file object or encapsulating both the file object and ID?

Comment: Where does it upload to? I'm afraid you can only change the file's content on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I believe that you can literally just use:

```
 t.id = i;
```

That should add an id element to the object.

Comment: Yeah, that works. I changed it to:             $.each($("#Files")[0].files, function (i, file) {
                file.id = i;

                files.push(file);
            });